# Filtering Pandas DF Containing All Elements of a List

Tags: python, pandas, string, filter

I have a data frame with a number of columns. One of the columns ("BLOCKED_YES") contains country codes strings e.g. 'CA CH HK EU UK DE'. The country codes can have a random order.

I want to isolate all rows which contain ALL of the elements of a ban list. For example if the ban list = ['CA','US'], I want to capture all the df rows with both these two elements present (regardless of order) in the BLOCKED_YES column.

I currently have the following

```
df = df[['STATUS','BLOCKED_YES','NAME']]
ban_list= ['US','CA']
df2 = df[df['BLOCKED_YES'].isin(ban_list)]
```

In the above case I get a df where the BLOCKED_YES columns contains strings with ANY of the elements in the ban_list, I want  rows which contain all of the elements in the list, not just one.

Comment: Do you have any programable data examples to start with and perhaps expected results data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're best off using `set`s for this instead of lists, as sets are conceptually unordered to begin with.

Let's assume your raw data is:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    (1, 'CA CH HK EU UK DE'),
    (2, 'CA CH HK EU UK DE US')
], columns=['id', 'countries'])
```

And your ban list is actually a set instead of a list:

```py
ban_list= {'US','CA'}
```

You can turn every cell content into a set as well like so:

```py
df['countries'].str.split(' ').apply(set)
```

and then use [`set.issubset`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html) to check if all elements are in (i.e. if the ban list is a subset of each entry). Chained together with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), it can be very concise:

```py
df[df['countries'].str.split(' ').apply(set).apply(ban_list.issubset)]
```

Comment: Conceptually this makes sense however, I get the following error - TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable  after I do the .str.split(' ').apply(set) bit

Comment: Figured it out, I think. I explicitly formatted the 'countries' column as a string which seems to have done the job i.e. df['BLOCKED_YES'] = df['BLOCKED_YES'].astype(str)

Comment: From your description, it seemed like it would be a string. Might be that the `.str.split()` was unnecessary / already done in the wider context.